# PyTorch - loading images without sub folders

Tags: python, conv-neural-network, pytorch

First of all I wanted to say that I am new to PyTorch, so i apologize in advice if the level of my questions is not that high.
I was wondering if you can help me with something (I actually have 2 questions). The story behind them: I am working on image classification. My test data is divided into sub folders based on their labels and I am loading them via DataLoader.

First question:
1) Is it true that if you have trained your model with specific batch sized, testing it with other sizes will affect the accuracy?
2) Is there a way to load and use the model with test data located in a single folder (without sub folders). DataLoader needs sub folders as far as i know.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It depends if you're using operations that depend on other items in the batch. If you're using things like [batch normalization](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.BatchNorm2d) it may, but in general if your network processes batch items separately, it doesn't.
2. If you check the documentation of [torch.utils.data.Dataset](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/data.html#torch.utils.data.Dataset), you will see that a dataset essentially only requires the `__len__` and `__getitem__` methods, where the former says how many items the dataset contains and the latter gets the `i`th item - be it an image and a label, an image and its segmentation mask, or other things. There is nothing stopping you from writing a custom Dataset. I suggest you take a look at source code of [DatasetFolder](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torchvision/datasets/folder.html#DatasetFolder) and modify it according to your needs.

Comment: Thank you! I will have a look at the documentation